# meteor instantiate template from variable

Tags: templates, meteor

I have a variable in JS, which could be the currentPage for instance.

and now i would like to do something like this:

```
{{> currentPage}}
```

Which, of course does not work!

I would actually like to write a Handlebars helper like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('currentPage', function(context, options) {
   var currentPage = ...;
   return Handlebars._defaultHelpers(">",currentPage);
}
```

But unfortunately ">" is not registered as a helper function in Handlebars and I don't know how to access this code.

I could also imagine using something like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('currentPage', function(context, options) {
    var currentPage = ...;
    document.body.appendChild(Meteor.render(Template[currentPage]));
    return "";
});
```

Which kind of works, but breaks the updating system.

If I return an HTML string, the template doesn't get updated anymore.

I think this is pretty common, but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: So you want to render a template depending on a variable? Have you considered using routing, like https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router

Comment: routing might be an option, if wanted to use this just in such an global example as 'currentPage', but I would actually like to use this multiple times on the same page depending on variables that I store in the Session variable.

Comment: This is actually useful for several things other than routing, and can exist along a typical router. I use such method for layouts, non-content page areas, modal windows and so on - in apps where I also have meteor-router or iron-router for managing content area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it without `>` mark. This is the method `renderPage` helper in Router, or `yield` in Iron Router, are defined.

html:

```
{{currentPage}}
```

js:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('currentPage', function(...) {
    var currentTemplate = ...;
    var templateData = ...;
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[currentTemplate](templateData));
});
```

You can omit the `templateData` part if you don't need it.

Comment: +1 This is the right way to do it and not that well documented.

Comment: Thx guys, I'll check it out later today. So far it looks good!